# Porque me sale error con <br />?

Tags: php

```
session_start();

<br /> //esta es la linea 5
<form method="post" action="?">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" >
<tr>
<td>Ingrese su nombre de usuario</td>
<td><input type="text" name="frmUsername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ingrese su contraseña</td>
<td><input type="password" name="frmPassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   :\xampp\htdocs\Curso_Users\user.php on line 5

Comment: Por favor pone todo el codigo asi te podemos ayudar

Comment: session_start(); va entro de etiquetas php <?php ?> ahi no veo donde estas separando el error te da en <br> que es HTML

Comment: Necesitas poner unos 4 espacios en blanco al principio de la línea para que te lo reconozca como código; si no lo reconoce como código los tags no aparecen.

Comment: Es como dice Gustavo abajo Martin y como yo puse aca el session es de php va entre etiquetas de php <?php session_start(); ?> y abajo de esto todo el html

Answer (score 3):

Antes del br deberías cerrar el tag de PHP con ?>, o sea, debería quedar así:

```
session_start(); ?>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gustavo , esto no es una respuesta amena para la pregunta , más bien es un comentario , por lo tanto debería ir donde corresponde, ademas de no estár muy completa, mira como [answer]. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, por hacerme notar el error. Había que cerrar PHP antes de <br />.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que es el error que menciona @Gustavo Cantero. Esta esperando la etiqueta de cierre de PHP antes que `'<'` perteneciente a `<br>` Debería quedar así:

```
session_start();
?>
<br /> //esta es la linea 5
<form method="post" action="?">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" >
<tr>
<td>Ingrese su nombre de usuario</td>
<td><input type="text" name="frmUsername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ingrese su contraseña</td>
<td><input type="password" name="frmPassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```